# Swift How to get an ASCII value from a character

Tags: swift, character, ascii, coercion

I simply want to get a single ASCII value from a single character in swift for a cipher that I'm doing. With the input of "A" I want to receive 65 for example. However, with the code

```
var str:String = "A"
var temp = str.utf8
print(temp)
```

"A" is printed to the console rather than what I would expect to be 65. Does anyone know a simple solution for this? Everywhere I search seems to think I want to get the integer 5 from the character "5"

Comment: try print(UInt32(temp))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get it from the String but from a [Character](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character) in a string, for instance

```
str.first?.asciiValue
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use string data method using `ascii` encoding to avoid invalid characters in the string using `allowLossyConversion`.

```
for ascii in str.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)!{
             print(ascii)
 }
```